# Algorithm to display matrix in relative position of coordinates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, transform, coordinate-systems

Is there any standard way or algorithm for below transformation of matrix in relative position in the space considering `x=0 and y=0`as origin and downward `y-axis` and rightward `x-axis` as positive axes.

```
[ [{x:36,y:14},{x:242,y:14}],
  [{x:36,y:133}],
  [{x:36,y:252}],
  [{x:36,y:371},{x:242,y:371},{x:446,y:371},{x:651,y:371}],
  [{x:242,y:490},{x:446,y:490},{x:651,y:490}] ]
```

Now because the length of this array of arrays is **5** and length of longest array within it is **4**, I need transformed matrix of size **5 * 4** in below format.

```
[ [{x:36,y:14},{x:242,y:14},null,null],
  [{x:36,y:133},null,null,null],
  [{x:36,y:252},null,null,null],
  [{x:36,y:371},{x:242,y:371},{x:446,y:371},{x:651,y:371}],
  [null,{x:242,y:490},{x:446,y:490},{x:651,y:490}] ]
```

In the above case there relative positions are preserved.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does the longest array always contain all of the `x` values? Or could you have something like `[ [{x:1,y:8},{x:2,y:8}], [{x:1,y:9},{x:3,y:9}] ]` where the output arrays have length 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution reduces out all the unique x values into sorted flat array first.

Then loop over each row of data and go through each row array splicing `null` into the holes

```js
let data =[ [{x:36,y:14},{x:242,y:214}],
  [{x:36,y:133}],
  [{x:36,y:252}],
  [{x:36,y:371},{x:242,y:371},{x:446,y:371},{x:651,y:371}],
  [{x:242,y:490},{x:446,y:490},{x:651,y:490}] ]
  
  
let xVals  = [...new Set(data.reduce((a,c)=>a.concat(c.map(({x})=>x)),[]))].sort((a,b)=>a-b)

data.forEach(row=>{
   xVals.forEach((x,i)=>{
      if(row[i] === undefined  || row[i].x > x){
          row.splice(i,0, null)
      }
   });
});

 data.forEach(arr=>console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check at this piece of code. Explanation will be commented there.

```js
function normalize(array){

 // Get the largest sub-array. We will save this as a reference
 // to use it later
 var longest_value = array.reduce((a,b)=>a>b?a:b)


 // map each element in the main array
 return array.map(function(a){ 

  // for each item return a modified copy of the largest one.
  // To do this we map it
  return longest_value.map(function(b,i){

   // we the item with the same x position in the current main array item
   var v = a.filter(r=>r.x==b.x)

   //if there is, we return it, is not we return null
   return v.length? v[0] : null
  })
 })
}


console.log(normalize([ [{x:36,y:14},{x:242,y:214}],[{x:36,y:133}],[{x:36,y:252}],[{x:36,y:371},{x:242,y:371},{x:446,y:371},{x:651,y:371}],[{x:242,y:490},{x:446,y:490},{x:651,y:490}] ]))
```

Comment: This is not working with other test cases Ex [ [{x:36,y:14},{x:242,y:14}],
  [{x:36,y:133}],
  [{x:36,y:252}],
  [{x:446,y:371},{x:651,y:371}],
  [{x:242,y:490},{x:446,y:490},{x:651,y:490}] ]  should give me  [{"x":36,"y":14},{"x":242,"y":14},null,null]
VM124:1 [{"x":36,"y":133},null,null,null]
VM124:1 [{"x":36,"y":252},null,null,null]
VM124:1 [null,null,{"x":446,"y":371},{"x":651,"y":371}]
VM124:1 [null,{"x":242,"y":490},{"x":446,"y":490},{"x":651,"y":490}] .